# JavaScript - The timer countdown is not working?

Tags: javascript, php

When user gives input to the field named Duration of form 
and after submitting the form the form is not settion for the given input value instead it is setting diectly to 0:00 and comes back to form

this is my form field

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label>Duration:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="duration" name="duration" value="1">
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is javascript  code for timer

```
function secondPassed() 
                {
                   var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
                    remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                      if (remainingSeconds < 10) 
                        {
                           remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                        }
                    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
                      if (seconds == 0) 
                         {
                           clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
                           window.location.href = 'http://localhost/copied/final_generate/slideshow.php';
                         } 
                    else
                         {
                          seconds--;
                         }
               }

                 var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

this is the `div`  where I want to dislay the time duration for given input

```
 <div class="timer" style= 'font-size: 25px;color:  #ffe6e6;'>Duration:
        <time id="countdown">
            <script> var seconds = <?php echo  $duration * 60; ?>;</script>
                <?php echo $duration; ?>
        </time>
    </div>
```

here is my submit button

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="GENERATE" id="gen"><br><br>
```

This is my full php code which contains my output format

```
<?php 

 require_once 'expression.php';

function get_input_data() {
$seed = $_POST['seed'] ?? rand();
$play = $_POST['play'];
$num_digits = intval($_POST['num_digits']) ?? 1;
$num_questions = intval($_POST['num_questions']) ?? 1;
$num_operands = intval($_POST['num_operands']) ?? 1;
$duration = intval($_POST['duration']) ?? 1;

// Read operations from the POST params and map the array that looks like 
//    ['Addition', 'Multiplication'] as  ['+', '*']

$operations_map = array(
    'Addition'       => '+',
    'Subtraction'    => '-',
    'Multiplication' => '*',
    'Division'       => '/',
);
$operations = array_map(function($operation_name) use ($operations_map){
    return $operations_map[$operation_name];
}, $_POST['operation'] ?? []);  

// generate expressions using the specified random seed
srand($seed);
$expressions = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_questions; $i++) {
    $expression = generate_expression($num_operands, $operations, $num_digits);
    $expression_string = implode(" ", $expression);
    $result = eval("return ($expression_string);");
    $expressions[] = compact("expression", "result");
}

return compact(
    'play',
    'seed',
    'num_digits',
    'num_questions',
    'num_operands',
    'operations',
    'expressions'
  );
 } 

function output_slideshow_header($data) {
extract($data);
if (!empty($operations)) {
    $num_operations = count($operations); //count selected operation
    ?>
    <select class="choices">
    <option value="1">Your choices are here !</option>
   <option value="1"><div style= 'font-size: 25px; color:  #ffe6e6;'><i>You have selected <?php echo count($operations) ?> operation(s): <?php echo implode(', ', $operations); ?></i></div><br></option>
         <option value="2"><div style= 'font-size: 25px;color:  #ffe6e6;'><i>No. of questions: <?php echo $num_questions ?></i></div><br></option>
          <option value="3"><div style= 'font-size: 25px;color:  #ffe6e6;'><i>Numbers you want: <?php echo $num_operands ?></i></div><br></option>
        <option value="4"> <div style= 'font-size: 25px;color:  #ffe6e6;'><i>No. of digits: <?php echo $num_digits ?></i> </div></option><br><br><br><br><br></select>

    <div class="slideshow-header flex-center flex-column">      
       </div>
       <div class="timer" style= 'font-size: 25px;color:  #ffe6e6;'>Duration:
        <time id="countdown"><script> var seconds = <?php echo  $num_questions * 60; ?>;</script>
                <?php echo $num_questions; ?>
        </time>
    </div>

       <br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <?php
  }
}

function output_slide($slide_data, $index=1) {
$expression = $slide_data['expression'];
$result = $slide_data['result'];
?>
<div class="slide flex flex-justify-center flex-column" id="out">
    <h3 class="ta-center">Q(<?php echo $index+1 ?>)</h3><br><br>
            <div class="expression flex flex-center flex-row" id="exp">
        <?php foreach($expression as $item) { ?>
        <span class="slide-item"><?php echo $item ?></span><!--displaying each item at a time-->
        <?php } ?>
        <span class="slide-item"> = </span>
        <span class="slide-item">
            <span class="answer flex flex-center">
                <span class="answer-placeholder">
                   ****
                </span>
                <span class="answer-content"><!--displaying result-->
                   <?php echo number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', ''); ?>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br>
     <center><div class="dotin"><?php
        for ($j=0; $j<count($expression); $j++) {
            ?><a class="dots-cont" onclick="goToItem(<?php echo $j ?>)"></a><?php
        }
    ?></div></center>
</div>



 <?php
}
function output_slideshow_controls($data) {
?>
<!--  go to next element of expression , for inner slider-->
<a class="goto-next-slide overlay-button overlay-right">Next</a>    
<a class="goto-prev-slide overlay-button overlay-left">Previous</a><br><br><br>
<a class="show-answer button" onclick="goToItem(<?php echo $j ?>)">SHOW  NEXT</a>
<button type="button" class="exit" 
    onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/copied/final_generate/slideshow.php'">X</button>

<div class="slideshow-controls center">
    <!--<a class="button goto-prev-slide">Previous</a>-->
     <!--<a class="button goto-next-slide">Next</a>-->
    <br><br><br>
   <div class="flex flex-center"><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<count($data['expressions']); $i++) {
            ?><a class="dot" onclick="goToSlide(<?php echo $i ?>)"></a><?php
        }
    ?></div>
</div>

<?php
}

function output_slideshow($data) {
?>
<div class="slideshow flex flex-column flex-center">
    <?php output_slideshow_header($data); ?>
    <div id="slides" class="slideshow-stage flex flex-center flex-column"><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<count($data['expressions']); $i++) {
            output_slide($data['expressions'][$i], $i);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php output_slideshow_controls($data); ?>
    </div><?php
   }
```

this is my form code

```
function output_form($data) {
extract($data);
 ?>  
 <div class="flex flex-center flex-column">
    <h2><i>GENERATE HERE !</i></h2>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="generator">
    <input name="seed" value="<?php echo $seed ?>" type="hidden" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="num_questions">Select No. of questions:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="num_questions" name="num_questions" value="1" min="1" max="100">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="int">How many numbers you want in a sequence? :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <select name="num_operands">
                    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                    <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="dig">Select no. of digits:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <select name="num_digits">
                    <option value="1"> 1 Digit </option>
                    <option value="2"> 2 Digits </option>
                    <option value="3"> 3 Digits </option>
                    <option value="4"> 4  - Mix Digits </option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label>Select operations:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="all" onChange="toggleCheckboxes.call(this, 'operation[]')">
                    All
                </label><br>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operation[]" value="Addition" checked>
                    Addition
                </label><br>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operation[]" value="Subtraction">
                    Subtraction
                </label><br>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operation[]" value="Multiplication">
                    Multiplication
                </label><br>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operation[]" value="Division">
                    Division
                </label><br>
            </div>
        </div>
         <br><br>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label>Duration:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="duration" name="duration" value="1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
         <input type="button" name="submit" value="GENERATE" id="gen">
         <input type="submit" name="play" value="PLAY" id="play" />
         <input name="reset" id="re" type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" />  

    </form>
        </div>



 <?php 
 //onclicking generate button show reset button also 
  if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    ?>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#re").hide();
                    });
     </script>
     <?php
   }
 }

function output() {
$data = get_input_data();
if (!isset($data['play'])) {
    output_form($data);
} else {
    output_slideshow($data);
   }
  }
 ?>
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is the submit button for the input form?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply , actually  the duration is one of my form field I am getting error in only this that's why I didn't posted submit button  code in this post , but if you want to see that I am updating the post above

Comment: @ Ahmad  I have updated the submit button above , can you check it out?

Comment: Where I went wrong?

Comment: Can I see the PHP Code you used to get the duration?

Comment: @Jonathan K  Thanks for the reply can we discuss this  in chat

Comment: @Jonathan K so that I can shre the code with you

Comment: @Jonathan K   I have updated my full output code in the above post. can you please check it out  and guide me ?